# Rising memory usage after start new activities

Tags: android, android-intent, memory, memory-management

Similar case with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326061/repeated-activity-initializations-and-memory-usage), my App uses multiple activities to display different sections. With a sliding menu's button, I can switch from one activity to another. Codes are as follow:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

similar for other menu buttons, which switch to Activity B, C and D. When I switch from A to B, memory usage is 30MB; then I switch from B to C, memory usage is 35MB; then I switch from C to D, memory usage is 40MB; then I switch from D to A, memory usage is 45MB.

When I click "Force GC" in Android Studio, memory usage drops by 5 to 10MB only. How can I stop memory usage from increasing non-stop ?

Last, here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityA"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityB"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityC"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityD"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: you can't. The GC will take care of it when the system decides it is time for it to run. Unless you are leaking memory you shouldn't worry about it

Comment: but I randomly encounter OOM as Picasso spends quite a lot memories during loading images into `RecyclerView`. Repeat starting activities cause memory to raise and fill up the heap. Can `launchMode` = `singleTop` help?

Comment: @Blackbelt it seems clear from the description that the app **is** leaking memory.

Comment: You are leaking memory. You have memory allocations in your activities that are not being freed properly. You'll need to take a hard look at your activity code to see where you are leaking memory. Do you have any `static` member variables?

Comment: @DavidWasser that's indeed very likely

Comment: I just found out there is a static `ArrayList` that contains a back stack of activities, which makes the memory used by previous activities could not be released. (facepalm)